# PHP line break with file_put_contents()

Tags: php

I can't seem to figure out why the following code doesn't produce a new line in my text file - neither does using \n etc either - any ideas what could be wrong?

```
    $data = $name . ' | ' . $_POST['comment'] . PHP_EOL;

    //write to file
    $f = file_put_contents('posts.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you viewing the text file in an internet browser by any chance?

If you are, the browser will get rid of the newline characters (unless you're using PRE tags).

Answer (score 1):

Try double quotes: `$data = $name . ' | ' . $_POST['comment'] . "\n";`
Or: `$data = "$name | {$_POST['comment']}\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried \r or \n\r ? Just an idea.